# Create a grid with an ng-repeat Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list and I want to sort my items with a filter, where it is shown from highest to lowest according to the score of each person. I just want to show the top 8 of the 13 that exist. I would like to have a  grid showing the highest to lowest score from left to right.
[image]

I can increase the score of a person by clicking on the 'sum score' button and entering the index of the object. I have no idea how to have this grid by default and that only people change.

```
<span ng-repeat='item in list | orderBy: "-score"'>
<p style='display:{{$index>7?"none":"block"}}'>
  {{item.name}} score {{item.score}}
</p>
</span>
<h2>index min 0 - max 12</h2>
<button ng-model='btn' ng-click='sumKey()'>Sum Score</button>
<input type='number' ng-model='mytext' max=12 min=0>  

$scope.list=[
 {'name': 'pedro', 'score':1},
  {'name': 'miguel', 'score':2},
  {'name': 'juan', 'score':3},
  {'name': 'david', 'score':4},
  {'name': 'yeison', 'score':5},
  {'name': 'doraemon', 'score':6},
  {'name': 'goku', 'score':7},
  {'name': 'vegeta', 'score':8},
  {'name': 'seiya', 'score':9},
  {'name': 'bruno', 'score':10},
  {'name': 'faver', 'score':11},
  {'name': 'cane', 'score':12},
  {'name': 'brye', 'score':13}
]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLrft3nx/

Thank you

Comment: Are you using any frontend libraries, like Bootstrap or Material design?

Comment: @tavnab only bootstrap..

Comment: @tavnab I only use the class .row .cols ...

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/bLrft3nx/1/

Comment: @yogendarji it not works...

Answer (score 1):

For the limiting to the top 8, you can use the `limitTo` filter:

```
<span ng-repeat='item in list | orderBy: "-score" | limitTo: 8'>
  <p>
    {{item.name}} score {{item.score}}
  </p>
</span>
```

For the grid, since you mentioned Bootstrap (I'll assume 3.x, but it should apply to other versions), you can define a single row with multiple columns of class `col-md-3` (and other sizes if you want to be responsive). This will effectively create a grid with 4 columns per row (since the Bootstrap grid is 12 slots wide, and it'll wrap to the next line every `12 / 3 = 4` columns).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat='item in list | orderBy: "-score" | limitTo: 8'>
    <p>
      {{item.name}} score {{item.score}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Update

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z945hbpa/) that demonstrates it. I also added classes `col-sm-3` and `col-xs-3` to account for the small size of the preview area; you can include all of the `col-*-3` classes if you want to ensure it's always a grid, regardless of viewport size.

### Update 2

You can just replace `col-md-3` with `col-xs-3` if you want the grid to apply to all viewport sizes; no need to add all the `col-*-3` classes. The snippet above has been updated, and here's [another jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o86k35v7/).

Comment: thanks, I tried your code but not works.. http://jsfiddle.net/t8emvq5w/

Comment: I suspect it was because of the small preview area of jsfiddle. See my update.